# GT Bike model and year?

Tags: mountain-bike, identify-this-bike, hardtail

[image]This bike is being offered to me, but i cant find the model and year pls help! I think it might be a GT Zaskar or a GT Avalanche mustang, but the GT winged logo makes me doubt. Thanks

Comment: Probably not a GT. Their mountain bikes have a very distinctive triple-triangle frame. Maybe a generic bike with aftermarket GT stickers.

Comment: Consider asking the owner for the sales receipt.  They'd need to keep that for warranty - a "lifetime warranty" on the frame can still be rejected without paperwork.

Comment: It appears to lack either the classic or the modern "triple triangle" design. I haven't been able to find any images of a GT mountain bike with the winged GT emblems.  I would be suspicious as the model is not evident.

Comment: @WarrenBurton - without commenting on the authenticity of this bike, some smaller GT frames have been made without the triple-triangle.

Comment: @DWGKNZ It is a small frame. The welds look relatively clean so its possibly GT brand. But definitely not a Zaskar or Avalanche.

Comment: I thought I'd found an example of an old small avalanche without the triple triangle, but it was actually present (but much smaller than often seen)

Comment: Maybe take a look at some of the componentry.  GT often use their All Terra brand on some of the more entry level bikes.  Check grips, seats etc. at least that can help verify it being GT or not

Comment: Do not rely too hard on the triple triangle, as they also produce BMXes, and maybe some "BMXes for grown-ups" too. You may want to consult [GTs catalogs](https://www.gtbicycles.com/usa_en/catalogs) dating back as far as 2009; there may be some older catalogs available from other sites.